# Are there any advantages to regularly running Eclipse as Administrator?

Tags: eclipse

Sometimes I have to run Eclipse as admin in order to install certain (Android) SDKs, but is there any advantage (or disadvantages) to simply *always* running Eclipse as admin? If there *are* advantages, is there a way to set it up to do this without having to select "run as admin" from the context menu each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to run ever Eclipse as Administrator, it is only needed when you need to write protected files or install some additional SDK that require elevated privileges .

However if you want to run as admin each time that you launch it, you can **right click on its icon** and then **Properties** then **Compatibility tab** and check **Run This Program As An Administrator** check box, and then click **OK** .

Answer (score 2):

At least on Indigo there are reports of certain modules/plugins being properly functional only when Eclipse has admin rights. It is mostly a UAC issue (and perhaps with the help of bad programming) that Windows users have to grapple with from time to time.

As a side note, I don't run Eclipse regularly, I simply keep it running for a long time since it takes so long to start it up.